# Hard browser refresh using nwjs on Mac

Tags: nwjs

Is there a way to do a hard browser refresh when running an app with nwjs, on Mac?  nwjs's right click 'simulate browser restart' seems to start the app at its entrypoint again.  Is there a way to simulate the behavior of simply clicking the shift reload button in Chrome?

Answer (score 4):

There is an nwjs api for this:

```
// Load native UI library
var ngui = require('nw.gui');
// Get the current window
var nwin = ngui.Window.get();
// this will do a hard refresh
nwin.reloadIgnoringCache();

// here's a regular refresh
 nwin.reload();
```

nwjs doc:

http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/References/Window/#winreloadignoringcache

Answer (score 1):

just use javascript reload

```
location.reload();
```